# Unit testing procedural C code

Tags: c, unit-testing, embedded

I just went through this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wEhu57pih5w) on unit testing. It gives good pointers on unit testing object oriented code. Are there any good documents / books / tips to write a unit testable procedural `C` code ?

Answer (score 1):

This could give you plenty of ideas: [Test Driven Development for Embedded C](http://pragprog.com/book/jgade/test-driven-development-for-embedded-c). I really liked that one. By the time I was reading it though, I had quite a lot of experience of developing embedded systems with unit tests.

Comment: I have already gone through this book. This book gives you insights on how to unit test embedded systems in general. Like maintain multiple target (both PC and MCU), run tests more frequently on PC and less frequently on MCU. Introduces you to UT frameworks like UNITY, CppUtest etc, but the book does not give pointers on writing unit testable code. Like coding patterns that make unit test easy.